# How to find a nonstandard basis in the set of all diagonal 2x2 matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find a nonstandard basis for D, the set of all diagonal 2x2 matrices. Prove that your set is a basis, and then find the dimension.

I also need to find a nonstandard basis for U, the set of all upper triangular 2x2 matrices.

I get how to find a standard basis, but I don't know how to make a nonstandard basis.

Comment: One way is to construct new vectors from the standard basis vectors; just make sure the vectors in your candidate basis are linearly independent. E.g., a non-standard basis for $\mathbb R^2$ would be $\{ (1,2), (3,4) \}$

Answer (score 2):

There is one method of searching nonstandard basis of any space:

1. Find dimension of space, for example by finding standard basis $\text{dim} \;D=2$.
2. Choose any vector from space that is not in standard basis, for example:

$$v_1=\begin{bmatrix}1 && 0 \\ 0 && 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Let $B_{1}=\{v_1\}$

3. For $n=2,3,\cdots,\text{dim} \;D$.Choose any vector from space that is not in $\text{lin}\; B_{n}$ For example:

$$v_2=\begin{bmatrix}1 && 0 \\ 0 && -1\end{bmatrix}$$

Let $B_{n+1}=B_{n}\sum \{v_{n+1}\}$.

4. $B_{\text{dim} \;D}$ is non-standard basis of vector space.